# Oracle exploit parallel execution in DMS (i.e. UPDATE query)

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing, sql-update, query-hints

As you can see at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965978/oracle-update-performance-issue-and-optimization) sometimes the `PARALLEL HINT` doesn't work in forking parallel execution of an update query.

For select I must even force a `FULL TABLE SCAN` or a `FAST FULL INDEX SCAN`. How does it work for DML statement?

I used the directive `alter session enable parallel dml;`

If you look at the IO of the linked topic. Just one thread is making read / changes.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle only uses parallel execution for UPDATE or DELETE statements when they affect multiple partitions.  Both variants of your query seem to include the partition key in their sub-queries: are you certain that the values in the temporary tables will cover several partitions?